# Changing \eqref colors in Beamer

Tags: beamer, color

I want to change my equation reference color to `\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}`. I use it as `{\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\ref{eqn1}}` but I want to make this as my default color and just use `\eqref{eqn1}` to get the same output.

Also, where can I find the list of colors that beamer uses?
For example, for example block header, alert block header, theorem block header.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsfonts}


\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{equation}
y^{\prime}=p(x)y\label{eqn1}
\end{equation}
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\eqref{eqn1}} is a linear differential equation of first order.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a minimal example to play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just redefine `\eqref` to incorporate the color change:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\eqref[1]{%
  \textup{\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{equation}
y'=p(x)y\label{eqn1}
\end{equation}
\eqref{eqn1} is a linear differential equation of first order.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I also edit this for \ref and \cite?

Comment: @bkarpuz That's more difficult, because `\ref` and `\cite` are not really supported by `beamer`. And `\cite` may depend on the bibliography package manager you use, for instance `natbib` or `biblatex`. In my opinion `\ref` and `\cite` should be used very sparingly in a `beamer` document.

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine the internal macro `\tagform@` to tell it to render its output in blue (or whatever color you prefer).

I'd consult chapter 17, "Colors", of the beamer user guide for information about all colors that beamer and its various styles use.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter   % add "\color{blue}" to argument of "\maketag@@@"
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{blue}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{equation} \label{eqn1}
y'=p(x)y 
\end{equation}

\eqref{eqn1} is a linear differential equation of the first order.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just want to change \eqref color not the equation color. Is that possible?

Comment: @bkarpuz - Visual cues are least likely to be misinterpreted if they are used consistently: If you want to color an equation number in a cross-reference, it's helpful to your audience if the original equation number uses the same color.

Comment: My idea is just to make clickable links colored.

Comment: To make all cross-references colored, you're better off simply loading the `hyperref` package with the option `colorlinks`.